# adding items to shoping cart using php

Tags: php

I am trying to add item to cart.when I added same item to cart it showing as new item in cart..some errors in my loop.can any one help me to find the issue?

if(!empty($_POST["pro_Count"])) {

```
    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) { 
        $_SESSION["cart_item"]=array();
    }
    
    $productid= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['pro_Id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableposts where id =$productid";
            
             $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
             $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
    
    
             // $rowCart[]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
             
           // $itemArray = array($row['id']=>array('id'=>$row['id'],'name'=>$row['title'],'quantity'=>$_POST["pro_Count"], 'price'=>$row['saleprice']));
             
             $itemArray = array($row['id']=>array('id'=>$row['id'],'name'=>$row['title'],'quantity'=>$_POST["pro_Count"], 'price'=>$row['saleprice']));
        
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                        $cartCodeArray = array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            if(in_array($row['id'],$cartCodeArray)) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                                        if($row['id']== $k){
                        
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"]+$_POST["pro_Count"];
                        
                                        }
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
        }
    
      
            // $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);

}
```

Comment: You should provide more context to the code as well as the errors you receive and on which lines.  This is a large body of code that is ambiguous.

Comment: When I adding same item it is not increating quantity but add item as new item in the cart array. Is this line correct ?if(in_array($row['id'],$cartCodeArray)) {

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a plenty much of copy/paste mess ;-)

so i wont go into detail, what to do in your code (because: just delete and rewrite it).

How I would do it in short:

- in session you create a "cart" object array (key of this array should be the id or slug of the product)
- if a page request params says "add  of  to cart" - modifiy the entry in the session-array/-object

Comment: yes , you are right...bcoz I am a new bee in programming.. :)...cart session and design are done. But In array I have lots of confusion :(

Comment: Can you help me to find out the issue with array?

Comment: if(in_array($row['id'],$cartCodeArray)) {